# Is it possible to make a header file to center text? - In Console

Tags: c++

I'm trying to center text in a function, but define the function in a header file called center.h

center.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void centerStr(string* str) {
    int consoleWidth = 80;
    cout << setw(consoleWidth / 2) << " " << str << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "center.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
    system("clear");
    cout << centerStr("Unit Converter By DualKeys") << endl << 
    endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In main.cpp I keep getting an error saying "No matching function for call to centerStr"

[EDIT] Yes, ***I have*** tried defining centerStr in the ***main.cpp*** file

Comment: The parameter has to be `const char *` or `std::string`, voting to close as a typo...

Comment: You will violate the ODR if you add a second source file that uses this header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833941/putting-function-definitions-in-header-files

Comment: are methods implemented in the header automatically public I wonder?

Comment: ***are methods implemented in the header automatically public I wonder?*** This is a free function.

Comment: First comment answered -- compiler is right and you are wrong, no matter where you put the wrong code. But I want to add: Don't put "using namespace std" in a header. It's okay to be sloppy in a small program, but in a header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me to be an incredibly messy way of setting things up but anyway.
I would avoid putting...

```
using namespace std;
```

in any header files or at all to keep the code clean.

center.h

```
//declaration
void centerStr(const char*);
```

center.CPP

```
#include "center.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

//definition
void centerStr(const char* str) {
    int consoleWidth = 80;
    std::cout << std::setw(consoleWidth / 2) << " " << str << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "center.h"

int main() {
    centerStr("Unit Converter By DualKeys");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

You will need an overload for an std::string version of this function or a function template may suffice.

```
template<typename T>
void centerStr(const T& t) {
    int consoleWidth = 80;
    std::cout << std::setw(consoleWidth / 2) << " " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Finally just declare consoleWidth as a global const variable. Seems wasteful to do it on each call! :)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `consoleWidth`, any half-decent compiler will optimize it out. Also, making it global would pollute the global namespace.

Comment: The real issue is "passing the wrong type results in an error." It doesn't matter if it's in a header or not. The rest of this is codereview unrelated to a simple question with a mcve (and people downvoted it, weird).